# How to export data from hive to mysql?

Tags: hive

I am trying to export table in hive to mysql, but I am getting the following error:

```
bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/jobportal --table studentinfo  --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/studentsinforamtion --username root --password root -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001'
```

ERROR:

> 13/12/17 01:02:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312162139_0017_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
>
> at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java

Can you please provide the solution for this?

Comment: `please check task tracker logs` - I assume you have done that, and that this has given you further hints that you are going to post here any second.

Comment: TARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ubuntu/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-12-17 01:08:38,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties

Comment: can u please provide solution for this